# Fedora 22 on MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Tags: fedora, grub2, macintosh

I recently installed Fedora 22 on my new [MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

**Good news:**

- Wi-Fi works out of the box, so you can update the system immediately to resolve the faulty video driver issue (under bad news).  I had to boot into runlevel 3 to last long enough to get the updates.  Your machine will most likely crash before you can update otherwise.  Unfortunately, you'll need a USB keyboard so you can add `linux 3` to the grub boot since the `CTRL-X` combination won't work on the laptop's keyboard.

**Bad news:**

- System will crash after initial install due to some video driver issues (see above)
- Bluetooth is not present at all, no adapter found
- Touchpad doesn't have right-click or natural gestures
- Webcam also doesn't work, no device found

**Really Bad news:**

Here's where we get to the main reason for this post.  After installing Fedora 22 I am unable to boot back into the Mac OS X partition.  I successfully get the grub2 menu, and it **is** showing Mac 32bit and 64bit options, but when you select either of them you get the following errors:

```
error: can't find the command `xnu_uuid`.
error: can't find the command `xnu_kernel`.
error: can't find the command `xnu_kextdir`.

Press any key to continue...
```

The options are as follows under the boot menu:

```
Fedora (4.0.4-303.fc22.x86_64) 22 (Twenty Two)
Fedora (4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64) 22 (Twenty Two)
Fedora (0-rescue-{long hash}) 22 (Twenty Two)
Mac OS X (32-bit) (on /dev/sda4)
Mac OS X (64-bit) (on /dev/sda4)
```

Moreover, I am unable to do any of the Mac BIOS boot options (holding down `option/alt` or `command+R`

Anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

To boot MacOS from GRUB, you need just a single line in the MacOS entry: exit. This will exit GRUB and then the EFI firmware will use the second partition in the boot order, which should be your MacOS installation (if Fedora hasn't messed up the order, otherwise you would need to fix that with `efibootmgr`).

Comment: MacOS entry where? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

**MacOS Boot:**

I recently installed Fedora 22 on my MacMini Late 2014 and also lost the means of booting MacOSX.

I had previously installed Refind boot manager which I used to choose which OS (MacOSX or Fedora 20) to boot.

The good news (probably will also work for you) is that you can simply boot while pressing the ALT key and choose which EFI to boot on the original hfsplus MacOS partition (in my case I chose the refind boot).

Pressing the ALT key while booting detaches a simple embedded EFI boot manager every recent Mac has (and when booting with ALT key pressed, it will load even before grub).  Then, after booting with MacOSX, I reblessed the refind bootmanager and everything got back to work as before.

Additional note: I use refind to load elilo, which then loads Linux.  Please, be aware that after reblessing MacOSX (if you don't use refind) you will "lose" the capability of booting the new installed Fedora 22 (unless you boot with the ALT key again and chose it).  I recomend installing a more user friendly EFI boot manager as refind to not need to boot using the ALT key to chose which OS to use.

**Making the right button and gestures to work:**

I my MacBook Air mid 2011 I currently use Fedora 20 which works fine (will upgrade to 22 soon too), but I remember that some time ago, when I used to use Fedora 18 on it, I had to do some tuning for the synaptics driver to work with all the gestures.  I don't have the old config files to paste here anymore (`/etc/X11/xorg.d.conf/50-synaptics.conf`), but maybe these links can help you (I still have them in my bookmarks):

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150276
https://pseudomorph.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/macbook-synaptics-touchpad-too-sensitive-under-linux/

Good luck and please post back your results here.